# FSO DeleteFolder() method not working

Tags: vbscript, directory, exe, hta

I have a program in HTA and all the auxiliary files are in the same folder, a subfolder of the AppData folder. I created an uninstaller HTA which uninstalls the program by simply removing the folder with FSO `DeleteFolder()` method. I converted it to an executable with HtaEdit. (If you don't know this program, it doesn't matter). What the executable does is that it creates an HTA in a temporary folder (along with the auxiliary files) and runs it. The problem is that when it does the `DeleteFolder()` method, an error message comes up saying "denied access". I don't think that it's an administrator problem since it's in the current user's AppData folder. When I try deleting another folder that way, it works just fine. I think that there are usually problems deleting the folder containing an HTA file which is being run, but the HTA file isn't in the folder I'm trying to delete but in a temporary folder. However, it's been called by an executable in the folder I'm trying to delete.

I'm using VBScript, but it does the same thing if I use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a folder from within the same folder as long as there's still something holding an open handle to the folder or something inside it. For example, the following code will usually delete the parent folder of a VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
fso.DeleteFolder(dir)
```

or, in case of an HTA (which doesn't have a `WScript` object):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
htaPath = Replace(oHTA.CommandLine, """", "")  '<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA" ...>
dir = fso.GetParentFolderName(htaPath)
fso.DeleteFolder(dir)
```

These work, because the script interpreter [reads the entire script into memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/05/24/how-can-i-get-a-script-to-delete-itself.aspx) when the script is launched, so no open handle to the file remains.

However, the deletion of the folder will fail with a "permission denied" error if the folder is the current working directory of the script process, because in that situation there still is an open handle to the folder. The same applies if, for instance, the folder is open in Explorer or a command prompt.

You can check for open handles with [`handle.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle) or [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer).

Comment: The codes don't work. In the first one, `dir` is an empty string and in the second one, `oHTA` is undefined. I would like to know if there is a way to delete a folder which contains a file which is opened.

Comment: The first code snippet is for plain VBScript and will not work with HTAs, because the HTA runtime environment does not provide a `WScript` object. The second snippet is for HTAs, and you need to replace the `oHTA` with whatever you defined as the HTA application ID (`<hta:application id="oHTA" ...>`).